# SVN: Apache server won't start

Tags: apache, svn

Why in the world does Apache NOT start, when I uncomment the **two Famous lines** in httpd.conf ?

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

I added these 2 .so files from the bin folder of VisualSVNServer (for some strange reason, they weren't there in the latest SubVersion download).

Comment: Are there any errors in the log?

Comment: Latest Subversion download where? Do I understand you properly: you've copied these modules from VisualSVN Server installation to some other Subversion+HTTPD server?

Comment: Daniel, the log doesn't show anything. bahrep, the subversion came as a .zip file which didn't have the 2 mods.

Answer (score 0):

From [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html)

> Note that if mod_dav was compiled as a shared object (instead of statically linked directly to the httpd binary), you'll need a similar LoadModule statement for it, too. Be sure that it comes before the mod_dav_svn line:
>
> ```
> LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so
> LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
> ```

Thus, complete SVN-related LoadModule will be (with per-directory ACL)

```
LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

Comment: Well, I'll try this before I try David's suggestion. Its surely more doable.

Comment: I'm afraid, it doesn't work. (And I've tried so many other combinations earlier).

Answer (score 0):

Subversion with Apache httpd is a very tough nut. You have to compile Apache httpd, the Apache Portable Runtime Library (APR), the two modules, and Subversion all together at once. Neon must be the right version too, and you normally have to compile that from scratch. Add in dependencies like libz, and you can see why this can be so difficult. This is why these packages are so popular.

(Note: I don't know if APR or neon are still part of the latest Subversion version. There was talk at one time getting rid of these components)

Redownload VisualSVN again. Try an older version. If it's not good, use another prepackaged Subversion server for Windows. ColabNet's SubversionEdge is a server that includes Apache, Subversion, the Subversion C API, and ViewVC. It doesn't have a nice GUI front end, but there's not much administration with Subversion anyway. Configure the Apache httpd configuration, and run `svnadmin create` to create your repos.

Use Windows Active Directory via LDAP to control your permissions and you probably never have to touch the server again. Not having a graphical interface isn't that bad.

Comment: Hi David W. Thanks for that detailed reply. It's going to take me some time to understand and do what you suggested.

Comment: In case of Windows you can (**must** really) install precompiled binaries - and such Apache and SVN exist

Comment: Lazy Badger, I've installed the latest-est versions of Xampp, TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN server (only 3 days ago). David's solution sounds good, but the thought of compiling httpd, APR etc. is scary.

Comment: @Abhishek - just VisualSVN Server will be OK, or plain Apache and additional modules (for corresponding versions of Apache) from [Subversion for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/) will give you working SVN over http

Comment: @Abhishek I didn't say for you to compile all of that. I was explaining why you can't simply copy the Apache modules from one to another. Everything has to be done together. Try reinstalling VisualSVN. If that doesn't work, get the CollabNet Subversion Edge and try that. It doesn't have the GUI interface, but if you know enough about copying and installing the Apache modules, you don't really need the GUI.

Comment: @Abhishek TortoiseSVN doesn't have anything to do with VisualSVN because it is just a client. XAMPP could be causing you trouble since it also is an Apache install. Deinstall it, and try installing VisualSVN by itself.

Comment: Hello again people. That work was dumped on a newly hired system admin guy. On a Win 7 machine (32 bit), he re-installed VisualSVN server, and turned off firewalls, made some network-related settings, and got it working somehow. Interestingly, it had to do with neither http.conf nor Proxies in the network (problems that I'd read about the most).

Comment: @Abhishek I'm glad you got it working. VisualSVN is suppose to take care of the `http.conf` configuration for you. httpd uses either port 80 or 443, and those ports are usually not blocked at most sites and you usually don't need a proxy for internal servers.